# C++ How do I add User Control to a Form So I can transition between Panels

Tags: c++, user-interface, visual-c++, c++-cli, c++17

I've been working on panel switching or transitions for C++ with a click of a button.
So in the project I added a CLR User Control and named it MyUserControl. 
2 files were created MyUserControl.cpp and MyUserControl.h I've then rebuilded the project and from the toolbar I dragged MyUserControl on to my MainForm but an error comes up saying "Failed to load toolbox item 'MyUserControl'. It will be removed from the toolbox".

Any ideas on this problem?
On the MyUserControl.cpp I left it blank except for `#include "MyUserControl.h"`
Main form code:

```
#include "MyForm.h"
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace UiDesign;

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE inst, HINSTANCE prev, LPSTR cmd, int show)
{
    MyForm Form1;
    Form1.ShowDialog();
}
```

Cheers,
James

Comment: Source codes here: https://github.com/jamesgao8/Ui_Designs

Answer (score 1):

Giving an answer to this problem is limited as you have not explicitly shared the code snippet with us.

As per your second line, it seems entire implementation is in your header class.

Comment: I think control call has not been implemented in your MyUserControl.h class, so that it pops an error message, when you're clicking on it.

Comment: As per the code, you shared, MyUserControl object is not created anywhere. Without creating object, how are you planning to invoke the method?

Comment: Hi, 
Thanks for that, but how so how do I add the object?:)

Comment: @JamesGao, you can write a small class and call that object in MyUserControl.cpp or else you can write a private method inside MyUserControl.cpp itself.

Comment: Can you show how to call the object in the class in cpp?:) Thank, James

Comment: @JamesGao As per my understanding on the code, you shared, all controls are in MyForm.h file. Therefore, create an object of MyUserControl.h inside this class. Then call the method you wish. It seems to be a cyclic method calls, because I noted MyForm.showDialog() inside MyUserControl as well.

Comment: Hi, there's some jargons here that's a bit tricky for me to understand. It'll really helpful if you can modify and write the code and show me the modified code so that I can actually see the changes.